# css: Moving hr element to bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a problem on my simple css navigation bar.

I wanna move the second hr element to bottom like this:

[image]

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">
    <body bgcolor="#000000">
        <title>Terraria Extras</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <div id="section">
            <div class="logo">
                <h2>Terraria</h2>
                <h3>extras</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <hr>
                <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
                <li><b><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="download">Download</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="about">About us</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="twitter">Twitter</a></b></li>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And css:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar hr {
    border-color: #cc9900;
    float: none;
}
```

I'm sorry for my bad english. I hope you understand something what i mean. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `clear: left;` on the `.navbar hr` and it works.

When using floats, you always want to 'clear' the floats after that to stop bad things happening to your design. Take a look at https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar hr {
  border-color: #cc9900;
  float: none;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000">
  <title>Terraria Extras</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <div id="section">
    <div class="logo">
      <h2>Terraria</h2>
      <h3>extras</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <hr>
      <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
      <li><b><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></b></li>
      <li><b><a href="download">Download</a></b></li>
      <li><b><a href="about">About us</a></b></li>
      <li><b><a href="twitter">Twitter</a></b></li>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know why someone votes me down either. Probably so their answer shows up first. Else I'd like a reason also.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `clear:both` in hr class

```
.navbar hr {
    border-color: #cc9900;
    float: none;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the css according to the code and it will work

```
 .navbar hr {
    border-color: #cc9900;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want an inline list that why you added `float:left` but it's not the right way like you can see. By default `li` elements are block, so just change to `display: inline-block`

I recommand to you [this float property documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)
I recommand also to envelop your `li` with `ul` elements

**first solution**

**html** :

```
    <div class="navbar">
        <hr>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a></li>
            <li><b><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="download">Download</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="about">About us</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="twitter">Twitter</a></b></li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
    </div>
```

**css** :

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

the `overflow` property make me crazy, but if you think it's usefull...

If you want just a border-line in the top of you navbar and in the bottom you can use the property `border`, the following **second solution** :

**html** :

```
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a></li>
            <li><b><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="download">Download</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="about">About us</a></b></li>
            <li><b><a href="twitter">Twitter</a></b></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**css** :

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
}

.navbar {
    border-top: 1px solid #cc9900;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cc9900;
}
```

And remove the `.navbar hr` property inside of your css